# How to drag mutiple images from horizontal scrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

i am making an application were user can be able to select image from horizontal scrollview and one's the image is selected he should also be able to drag all the selected images?

i am able to select one image at a time and able to drag the single image but i want mutiple images to be select one after the other should be able to darg them one by one?

This my code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
        imagesName = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"hat3.png",@"hat4-1.png",@"t-shirt.png",@"t-shirt.png",
                  @"Untitled-2.png",@"logo1.jpg",@"logo2.jpg",@"logo3.jpg",nil];
        images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

        [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"t-shirt.png"]];
    imageView.center = self.view.center;



    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    int scrollWidth = 120;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,80);


    int xOffset = 0;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:0]];

    //for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
        for (int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
    {

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        //img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);a
        img.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
        //img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 160, 110);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(0+xOffset, 0, 60, 61);

        //img.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);
        NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];
        [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];         
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);
        [scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
        xOffset += 170;
    }

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    for(int index=0;index<[images count];index++)
    {
        UIImageView *imgView = [images objectAtIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,width =%f,height=%f",imgView.frame.origin.x,imgView.frame.origin.y,imgView.frame.size.width,imgView.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"x= %f,y=%f",[touch locationInView:self.view].x,[touch locationInView:self.view].y) ;

        if(CGRectContainsPoint([imgView frame], [touch locationInView:scrollView]))
        {
            [self ShowDetailView:imgView];
            break;
        }
    }
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects]; 
    int count = [allTouches count]; 

    if (count == 1) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([imageView frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view])) {
            imageView.center = [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

please help 
suggest me some tutorial

Comment: when pasting code here, please format it properly. someone else has to read your code & answer you. Kindly be courteous of that...

Comment: sir i am new to this site ... i really dn't have any idea about this stuff....i am sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

I think a good idea would be to bind all selected images into an NSMutableArray that maintains a reference to them - Add / remove them as they are being selected / deselected respectively. Then, in your "touchesMoved", instead of updating only the UIImageView receiving the touch, iterate over all the selected image views and change their centers as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: can you plz provide me some tutorial related to this stuff.............tht will be helpfull to me